# Virtual environment for a package

Tags: python, module, directory, package, python-venv

I am working on a program and access a set of custom modules. I organized the modules in a subfolder as own package with an `__init__.py`. Moreover, on the main level of the directory I have created a virtual environment that holds my dependencies. The folder structure is as follows:

```
project
+-- main_program.py
+-- venv
|   +-- cool_package.py
+---mypackage
|   +-- module1.py
|   +-- module2.py
|   +-- __init__.py
```

The issue is, that `module2.py` depends on a package I installed in `venv`. Running `module2.py` from `main_program.py` gives an error `"cool_package.py" not found`.

How do I organize stuff like that so that I can accesses `cool_package.py` from main_program.py with all the other needed packaged. And make `cool_package.py` accessible for the custom package with `module2.py` as well?

Comment: How are you importing `cool_package.py` — what line of code are you using?

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environement before running main_program.py ?

Comment: @JulienV I activated the virtual environment beforehand in the concole using "env\Scripts\activate.bat"

Comment: @martineau I am calling cool_package.py using "import cool_package" in the header of "module2.py"

Comment: @martineau Maybe your cool_package.py is not correctly deployed in your virtualenv. The usual way is to use pip3 install cool_package. Did you check that simple command `python3 -c 'import cool_package' ` ?

Comment: @JulienV: xm0riTzx is the one asking the question, not I.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you mean by your virtual env but based on your folder and file layout I think you need to add an `__init.py__` file to your venv folder to make it a package and then you should be able to `import venv.cool_package`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all answers - it eventually worked by properly activating the environment before running the script. Something must have gone wrong the first time - all works now and the folder structure is correct.

Best
Moritz